# MKMapView randomly panning to Antarctica

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

I have an app set in San Francisco, which plots points on a map.  Once the points are plotted, I use this code to zoom and pan the map to fit all the points:

```
//BASE_RADIUS = 0.0144927536
- (MKCoordinateRegion)regionFromLocations:(NSArray*)locations {
    if([locations count] <= 0) { 
        MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
        return region;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D upper = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D lower = [[locations objectAtIndex:0] coordinate];

    // FIND LIMITS
    for(MapPinModel *eachLocation in locations) {
        if([eachLocation coordinate].latitude > upper.latitude) upper.latitude = [eachLocation coordinate].latitude;
        if([eachLocation coordinate].latitude < lower.latitude) lower.latitude = [eachLocation coordinate].latitude;
        if([eachLocation coordinate].longitude > upper.longitude) upper.longitude = [eachLocation coordinate].longitude;
        if([eachLocation coordinate].longitude < lower.longitude) lower.longitude = [eachLocation coordinate].longitude;
    }

    // FIND REGION
    MKCoordinateSpan locationSpan;
    locationSpan.latitudeDelta = upper.latitude - lower.latitude;
    locationSpan.longitudeDelta = upper.longitude - lower.longitude;
    if(locationSpan.latitudeDelta < BASE_RADIUS) { locationSpan.latitudeDelta = BASE_RADIUS; }
    if(locationSpan.longitudeDelta < BASE_RADIUS) { locationSpan.longitudeDelta = BASE_RADIUS; }  //the smallest it gets is a mile.

    CLLocationCoordinate2D locationCenter;
    locationCenter.latitude = (upper.latitude + lower.latitude) / 2;
    locationCenter.longitude = (upper.longitude + lower.longitude) / 2;

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationCenter, locationSpan);
    return region;
}
```

I then zoom the map to this region using:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = [self regionFromLocations:_data];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];  //shows all the pins
```

This works about 95% of the time. The other five percent, the map zooms to Antarctica.  The strange thing is, I've caught the zoom in the debugger once, and the coordinates are inside San Francisco.  Any ideas on what may be happening here?

Comment: Sometimes even machine want a vacation. Maybe it misses it family? :)

Comment: Haha, Maybe it just really likes penguins and astrology. Feature, not a bug?

Comment: before returning region print locationCenter and locationSpan and see is they are proper. There is limit on maximum and minimum value of locationSpan. See if it lies within limits. Also ensure you are not setting map region in any other method simultaneously.

Comment: At the end of the for loop you could check to see if the lower.latitude had gone negative. If so printout the MapPinModel you're dealing with and see if it is sensible.